# What does a draw from a posterior distribution represent and interpreting probability?

Tags: bayesian

I am learning about Bayesian analysis and concerning the prior and posterior distribution. What is the random process that the prior and posterior distribution represent?

#### Simple examples

When we think of a random draw from a Bernoulli process, we think of flipping a coin. The draw or realization is the value of the coin flip. This outcome can be used to assess the probability of different events. $P(H)$ or $P(T)$

When we think of a random draw from a sampling distribution, we think of taking a new random sample from our population and calculating a statistic. We can then calculate probabilities for different statistics $P(T \le t)$.

#### Bayes

Given the prior $f(\theta)$ and posterior $f(\theta|y)$ what does a random draw mean from these distributions?

Depending on what the draw means what does $P(\Theta \le \theta)$ represent.